# Why cannot I get uint returns without 'view' modifier?

Tags: truffle, modifiers, view

I have very simple contract as..

```
contract myContract {
    function foo() public returns(uint) {
        return 10;
    }

    function foo1() public view returns(uint) {
        return 10;
    }    
}
```

But when I test my contract with truffle test.js(as follows).
Why the result is different with view and without view modifier?

here is parts of my test.js.

```
temp1 = await instant.foo1();
console.log("temp1 value : " + temp1);
assert.equal(temp1, 10, "should be 10 return");     
temp1 = await instant.foo();
console.log("temp1 value : " + temp1);
assert.equal(temp1, 10, "should be 10 return");
```

And it is my result.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function without a `pure` modifier, a `view` modifier or a `constant` modifier (which is equivalent to a `view` modifier) is assumed to be changing the contents of the block-chain.

This "change" is refereed to as *transaction*, and the value returned to the off-chain caller (e.g., `web3`) is a hash which encrypts the transaction.

The actual value that you return from the function can be used **only inside the block-chain** (i.e., by any other function which calls your function).

If you want this value to be accessible on the off-chain side, then you need to generate an `event` (inside the Solidity function) which contains it.

Then, on the off-chain side, you will need to decode the returned value (i.e., the transaction hash) in order to retrieve that value.

On-Chain Example:

```
contract MyContract {
    event MyEvent(address indexed sender, uint256 amount);
    function myFunction(uint256 a, uint256 b, uint256 c) external returns (uint256) {
        uint256 x = a * b + c;
        MyEvent(msg.sender, x);
        return x;
    }
}
```

Off-Chain Example:

```
let PARAMS = [ // This should reflect MyEvent
    {name: "sender", size: 160, indexed: true },
    {name: "amount", size: 256, indexed: false},
];

function decode(data) {
    let transaction = {};
    let index = "0x".length;
    for (let i = 0; i < PARAMS.length; i++) {
        if (!PARAMS[i].indexed) {
            let name = PARAMS[i].name;
            let size = Math.floor(PARAMS[i].size / 4);
            transaction[name] = web3.toBigNumber("0x" + data.substr(index, size));
            index += size;
        }
    }
    return transaction;
}

async function myFunction(myContract) {
    let hash = await myContract.myFunction(5, 6, 7);
    let transaction = decode(hash.receipt.logs[0].data);
    return transaction.amount; // should be 5 * 6 + 7
}
```

Please note that by `hash.receipt.logs[0]`, we are accessing the first event which occurred as a result of invoking `myContract.myFunction`. In other words, the index (in this case, `0`) indicates the number of the desired event by chronological order.

Answer (score 4):

Because without the `view` modifier, web3 (and thus Truffle JS tests, which uses web3) thinks it has to send a transaction. Sending transactions does not yield a return value from the smart contract.

Adding the `view` modifier tells web3 it can use `call` in order to get the function's return value. A `call`, however, cannot alter the contract's state. It cannot alter any storage variables.

If you want a function which alters the contract's state and does yield a value, you could create a function which emits an event. In that event, you could set the return value.

Comment: So, I can only check the value with an event function? Is there any way to get the correct value from even log? I mean, without view modifier, I want to make some test code using assert.equal. Thank you.

Comment: i think, in  `wbe3 0.x` you can always use the `.call` with any contract method, either it changes the state variables or not.

Comment: If you use `.call` like that, web3 will simulate a transaction. The actual contract state will not be altered.

Answer (score 1):

The view Modifier indicates, that you make no changes to the Blockchain and that the query of the uint wont require any gas cost.